# Capture click on Listview, to see what item was clicked, without selection changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have an implementation of list views within items controls. On a left click a property of the collection in the itemsource is set.
As described in the answer here :
[ItemsControl of ListViews, bind SelectedItem from each ListView where the amount of ListViews are dynamic, MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945063/itemscontrol-of-listviews-bind-selecteditem-from-each-listview-where-the-amount)

I would like to use something like a right click, on both unselected, selected or disabled items to extract the value from it in code behind, without changing the current selection.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can handle `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` event and set `e.Handled = true` in it.

Comment: This works to stop the selection changing, but I also need to know which ListView Item that click was on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to accomplish what I was looking for thanks to @Miamy and some extended searching.

```
private void ListView_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   DependencyObject originalSource = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
   while ((originalSource != null && !(originalSource is ListViewItem)))
   {
      originalSource = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(originalSource);
   }
   if (originalSource != null)
   {

   }
}
```